# Prove that : $\Omega =\frac{10^{n}-7}{3}$ Has many numbers not prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that : $n\in\mathbb{N^{*}}$

$$\Omega =\frac{10^{n}-7}{3}$$

Has many numbers not prime ?

My try :

$n=1$ then $\Omega =1$ not prime

$n=2$ then $\Omega =31$ prime number

$n=3$ then $\Omega =331$ prime number

$n=4$ then $\Omega =3331$ prime number

I have tried many value but I can't find in degree such that this number are not prime

Comment: **Note :** $333333331$ is not a prime.

Comment: The next few values are prime, but for $n = 9$, you get $333,333,331 = 17 \times 19,607,843$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit thanks ! So I will try all $n=1,..,9$

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't understand you ? Can you explain more

Comment: @Ross's Answers provides exactly what you need . Also $10^{16} \equiv 1\mod 17$ from [Fermat's little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit OK but how he know that $n=16k+6$ then all number are divisible by 17 ?

Comment: @EllenEllen The values of $\frac{10^{n}-7}{3}$ are prime for $n = 5, 6, 7$ and $8$. However, for $n = 9$, you get what I stated in my earlier comment, with the factoring I mention. Although you can do this by hand (e.g., with a calculator), I used Wolfram Alpha's [Factoring calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/factoring-calculator/) to make it easier for me to confirm the earlier values were all prime, plus to get the factorization I gave earlier for the $n = 9$ case.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac {10^9-7}3$ has a factor $17$ and $10^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$, so any number of the form $\frac {10^{16k+9}-7}3$ is divisible by $17$

Comment: How you can imaging $10^{9}$ ? Can you explain how you know factor $17$ and how $10^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{17}$

Comment: @EllenEllen Fermat‘s little Theorem

Comment: @EllenEllen:  I just searched for one that would factor using Alpha to get the first part.  For the second part I used Fermat's Little Theorem, which says $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for $p$ prime and $a$ coprime to $p$.  Every prime that has a full length repeating decimal will have a family of solutions like this and some others.  It depends whether you can solve $10^n\equiv 7 \pmod p$

Comment: $(10^{12+18k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $19$; $(10^{21+22k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $23$; $(10^{2+15k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $31$

Comment: $(10^{20+28k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $29$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  If I had thought more clearly, your last would have been the easiest to find.  Similarly $(10^{3+330k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $331$ and the same for all the primes we found.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://stdkmd.net/nrr/3/33331.htm)

Comment: in fact $(10^{3+110k}-7)/3$ is divisible by $331$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how we can prove it ? For example : $\frac{10^{12+18k}-7}\equiv 0\pmod{19}$ ??

Comment: As @RossMillikan indicated above, mod $19$:  $10^2\equiv5$, so $10^6\equiv11$, so $10^{12}\equiv7$, and $10^{18}\equiv1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem