# Prove that : $\frac{10^{18n+12}-7}{3}\equiv 0\pmod{19}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Prove that : ($n\in\mathbb{N}$)

$$\frac{10^{18n+12}-7}{3}\equiv 0\pmod{19}$$

I know that from little theorem :

$$10^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$$

So :

$$10^{18k}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$$

Now i will go to this step if $\operatorname{correct}$

$$10^{12}=100^{6}\equiv 5^{6}\pmod{19}$$

$$5^{6}=(5^{2})^{3}\equiv 6^{3}\pmod{19}$$

$$6^{3}\equiv 7\pmod{19}$$ 
So :

$$10^{18k+12}-7\equiv 0\pmod{19}$$

But my be :

$$\frac{10^{18n+12}-7}{3}\not\equiv 0\pmod{19}$$

Comment: Note that $19$ and $3$ are co-prime.

Comment: I presume this question arose from the comments on the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505957/prove-that-omega-frac10n-73-has-many-numbers-not-prime)

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=10^{18k+12}-7$.

If $19|a$ and $3|a$, then $19|(\frac a3)3$, and $19\nmid3$,

so, by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), $19|\frac a3$.

Comment: good sir thanks!